# bool from a struct lead to "error: expression must have class type"

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, boolean, compiler-errors

I have a struct defined as

```
struct sData{ 
idx * id; 
int * stime; 
bool * result;  
unsigned int N;
};
```

Then the code that uses it in

```
numeric compute(numeric e, sData swabs){
  numeric cache=0.0;
  int sid=0;
  while(sid<swabs.N){
    if(swab.result[sid]) 
      cache += log(e);
    else cache += log(1.0-e);
    sid += 1;
  }
  return cache;
}
```

but when compiling I get the error.

> paug_cuda.cu(602): error: expression must have class type

What is this supposed to mean.  what class type?  I'm using a bool in a logical expression.  what else could there be to this.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you tell us which line is 602?

Comment: I obviously trimmed it down to the relevant portions. But the line with the problem is the typo in line "if(swab.result[sid])"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`swab` -> `swabs` :)

The error means that you wrote something like X.Y and X is not an instance of a class/struct.

Comment: There is a time limit, from when you submit the question.  I was trying. It is marked now.